# meteor collection: find only if array is not null

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, conditional-statements

Imagine that I have the following find in mongo collection:

```
contentsCollection.find(
  { $and: 
    [
      { 
        "fields.fieldName": "title", 
        "fields.value": { $regex : searchForm.title, $options: "gi" } ,
      }, 
      { 
        "fields.fieldName": "course", 
        "fields.value": { $regex : searchForm.course, $options: "gi" } ,
      }, 
      { 
        "fields.fieldName": "description", 
        "fields.value": { $regex : searchForm.description, $options: "gi" } ,
      }, 
      {
        "fields.fieldName": "language", 
        "fields.value.value": { $in: searchForm.language } 
      }, 
    ]
```

I just want to search language if searchForm.language is not a empty?

How should I do it?

Comment: I think your query was wrong. It should be:
`collection.find (
  {
    model: {$in: models },
    colors: {$in: colors}  
  }
)`

You build the query condition like:
`const conditions = { model: { $in: models } };
if (colors.length) conditions.colors = { $in: colors };
collection.find(conditions)`

Comment: Hum... Interesting... I will change the query to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to build the selector programmatically:

```
const selectors = [{ 
    "fields.fieldName": "title", 
    "fields.value": { $regex : searchForm.title, $options: "gi" },
  }, { 
    "fields.fieldName": "course", 
    "fields.value": { $regex : searchForm.course, $options: "gi" },
  }, { 
    "fields.fieldName": "description", 
    "fields.value": { $regex : searchForm.description, $options: "gi" },
  }
];

if (searchForm.language) {
  selectors.push({
    "fields.fieldName": "language", 
    "fields.value.value": { $in: searchForm.language } 
  });
} 

contentsCollection.find({ $and: selectors });
```